# How to erase outside bounding box of polylines?

Tags: wpf, polyline

I want to erase the outside part of the bounding box as shown on the sample below, erase as I wanted to make it transparent, how do I do it? does anybody has an idea about this?

[image]

Comment: It should be by default (`PolyLine` doesn't have a `Background` property). Can you post your XAML?

Comment: Do you look for clipping: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx? Anyway: in which world is an *area* a poly*line*?

Comment: @HimBromBeere When you set the `Fill` property of `PolyLine`, in the "WPF World" ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, with `the outside part of the bounding box` you mean the part you labeled as `Outer area`, not the **actual outside** of the `Bounding box`, right?

Comment: The sample is not generated from xaml..i am creating an application like a paint,in which the whole window is a canvas then you can draw whatever you want like an irregular shape,then as of now my closing for the polyline is a line that gets the first point and last point of the polyline to join.

Comment: @N.Gianan Ok, still not sure what you want to change. What makes you think the `Outer area` is **not** transparent. Would this be apparent on a screenshot maybe? Or is it something regarding mouse input (HitTest)?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yes its inside the bounding box, i want to create a picture from it so imagine that the bounding box will be my whole picture but transparent and the only thing is seen is the shape,output is something like that.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer still not sure yet if the outside part is transparent,maybe because my form is white.

Comment: Seems to me the problem is with your picture creating code. If you could post that here (edit question) maybe we can help. See: [mcve]

Comment: could you provide XAML or code for that?